# Why does Math.Tan(90) provide a non-undefined value?

Tags: c#, math, floating-point

While working with `Math.Tan()` I found that the result for 90 degree is not undefined. But is, inturn *1.6331779e+16*

Here is the screenshot for the app

[image]

Here is the code,

```
// convert to degrees
angle = (Convert.ToDouble(op1) * Math.PI / 180);
// write the output
FinalResult.Text = Math.Tan(Convert.ToDouble(angle)).ToString();
```

Why is such behaviour, is it expected?

Comment: Typical round-off error. Your `pi/2` isn't exactly `pi/2`.

Comment: What happens when you put `180.0` instead of `180`?

Comment: @Cobra_Fast I get 1.99 now .. O.o confusing though, So I guess I would have to write this one myself, like `if(value == 90) { FinalResult.Text = "undefined"; }` something like that I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The calculation is done with floating point numbers which are not perfect (not that `Math.PI` can ever be perfectly represented as a decimal anyways).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

and more specifically..

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536144/why-does-the-google-calculator-give-tan-90-degrees-1-6331779e16

If you want a rounded result then check the input for something like `>89.9999 && <90.00001`. Don't use `==` with floating point values.

For explanation of why not to use `==` with floating point numbers, try running this example:

```
var d = 0.2;
for(double k = 1.0; k<100; k++) {
    var t = 0.2 * k;
    t = t / k;
    Console.WriteLine("{0} == {1} ==> {2}", d, t, d == t);
}
```

We're multiplying 0.2 by a whole number, dividing it by the same whole number, and then comparing to 0.2. It should be true every time, right? It's not. Many times it returns false.

Comment: Yeah, that one makes some sense, so this is just `Math` and not a graph table from where they acquire values. They (C#) do this on RunTime.

Comment: Why is `==` bad with Floating point values? Can you tell me please,

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan, I added an example that shows `==` doesn't work properly with floating point.

Comment: +1 for the example, its really getting interesting about `float`ing point numbers.

Comment: Your suggestion makes the function return “undefined” for 89.9999, which is terrible compared to the best answer that could have been given, near 572957.8. But it is even worse! Maybe the user was doing a computation that should have produced 89.9998, and it produced 89.9999. Then the answer should be near 286478.9, and your suggestion is making the program produce “undefined”. Absolutely terrible.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, `undefined` is exactly what the original poster asked for. If more precision is needed then the bounds number can be adjusted.

Comment: @SamuelNeff The OP wants `tan(90)` to return `undefined`, which is a reasonable request. You told the OP how to make `tan(89.99995)` return `undefined`, which is abysmally stupid. You might as well make `tan(0.00005)` return the same as `tan(0)`, because that's probably what the caller meant, right? You are right, “the bounds number can be adjusted”. The only adjustment that makes sense is to return the best approximation you can of the argument that was passed. If (90 - 2^-15) is passed, then the tangent of that number should be returned.

Answer (score 4):

This question has been addressed (and answered, quite thoroughly) over on https://math.stackexchange.com/ in the question [Why does the google calculator give tan 90 degrees = 1.6331779e+16?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536144/why-does-the-google-calculator-give-tan-90-degrees-1-6331779e16)

or in other words ... You need to read David Goldberg's paper, ***What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic***. You can purchase a copy from the ACM (or download one if you are a member of the ACM) at http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=103163. Other versions are available, *gratis*, as well.

A copy of the original is at http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/goldberg.pdf. Also:

- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html
- https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Double/paper.pdf

And CiteSeer links to other locations as well:

- http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.22.6768

Comment: +1 for the suggestions you gave. :) I would definitely give some time to your suggestion, thanks! :)